# Adding A* to pgrouting plug-in

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, qgis-plugins

I am using pgrouting layer plug-in as described in this post:
http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/osm2po-part-2-pgrouting-on-osm-the-easy-way/

I am now able to calculate the shortest path using Dijkstra algorithm.

Is it possible to add to the pgrouting plug-in the A* shortest path algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

I am improving [pgRoutingLayer](https://github.com/sanak/pgRoutingLayer) plugin which is based on original pgRoutingLayer plugin.

This one includes all of non-wrapper functions (shortest_path_*/driving_distance/alphashape/tsp).

[image: shortest_path search]
[image: shortest_path_astar search]